# How can I fix these nuget package conflicts so my project can bulld?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Here are the conflicts:

[image: Screenshot of conflicts]

Here is the text in the image:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow' with identity 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk' with identity 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\Developer Training 2.0\LVP.MadeUpOrganization\LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity\CSC 1   Active
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\Developer Training 2.0\LVP.MadeUpOrganization\LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity\bin\Debug\LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity.dll' could not be found    LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity.UnitTest    C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\Developer Training 2.0\LVP.MadeUpOrganization\LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity.UnitTest\CSC    1   Active
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity         
Warning CS0168  The variable 'e' is declared but never used LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\Developer Training 2.0\LVP.MadeUpOrganization\LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity\Activity\WorkflowActivity1.cs   39  Active
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. LVP.MadeUpOrganization.Activity.UnitTest
```

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
Here are more screenshots:

[image: References]
[image: References being used]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk version 6 installed, but you need the 8 version so it will be compatible with your Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.

You can either upgrade Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk to 8 or downgrade Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow to 6.

Comment: I just figured this out. I reverted the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies package (which contains Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk) to 6.1.2 and it built fine!

Comment: However, I will note that updating the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies package will break it and I have no idea how to update the out-of-date Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk in the bin/coretools directory of the project since it seems later versions of the Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies package no longer uses that directory.